# How do I change the Text of A tkinter Label without pressing a Button in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, label

How do I update the Label of this code without pressing a button?

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
main=Tk()
main.attributes("-fullscreen", False)
lo=open("/xxx/xx/x.l" , "r")
l=lo.read()
lo.close()
info=Label(main, text="Watch Log of COW")
log=Label(main, text=l)
log.config(text=l)
info.pack()
log.pack()
main.mainloop()
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.  What do you mean by "without pressing a button"?

Comment: It looks like you're already doing it. What do you expect this code to do, and how is that different from what it's actually doing?

Comment: constantly changing the Label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to monitor the update of the file periodically and update label if the file is changed.  Use file last modification time to check file change and `.after(...)` to check it periodically as below:

```
import os
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

Label(text='Watch Log of COW').pack()
log = Label(text='abc')
log.pack()

last_mtime = None
cow = '/xxx/x.l'

def monitor_file_change():
    global last_mtime
    mtime = os.path.getmtime(cow)
    if last_mtime is None or mtime > last_mtime:
        with open(cow) as f:
            log['text'] = f.read()
        last_mtime = mtime
    root.after(1000, monitor_file_change)

monitor_file_change()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the file you're using on my system I can't provide a perfect solution, but perhaps `l` is not a string? Have you tried:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
main=Tk()
main.attributes("-fullscreen", False)
lo=open("/xxx/xx/x.l" , "r")
l=lo.read()
lo.close()
info=Label(main, text="Watch Log of COW")
log=Label(main, text=str(l))
log.config(text=str(l))
info.pack()
log.pack()
main.mainloop()
```

where you try use `str(l)` to explicitly convert it to a string? It would be helpful if a full traceback of your error was provided. Perhaps the error is in opening your file? Have you tried:

```
with open("/xxx/xx/x.l" , "r") as lo:
    l=lo.read()
```

Or maybe the error is using `.config()` instead of `.configure()` (that's what I've always used, I don't know the difference between them)

Your question is too broad for us to really help

Comment: Doesn´t work...

Comment: *HOW* does it not work. You still have not provided us an error message, or access to the file you are reading. We cannot help you otherwise. Edit your post please

Comment: there is no error message. The Label just doesnt change.

Comment: Well on my machine when I substituted "l" it updated and the GUI just showed `l`. There is probably an error reading your file or something. Try using print statements or something...

Comment: try changing the contents of the file. The Label will not Update

Comment: try changing the contents of *what* file? I already explained my machine doesn't just magically contain a file `"/xxx/xx/x.l"`. You need to include it in your post, or have a snip of what is inside it...